# DrRacket mutually recursive functions with accumulator

Tags: racket

```
  (define-struct person (name house kids))
```

;; A Person is (make-person String String ListOfPerson)
;; interp. A person, with name, house and list of children.

```
  (define P0  (make-person "Draco"      "Slytherin"  empty))
  (define P1  (make-person "Nymphadora" "Hufflepuff" empty))
  (define P2  (make-person "Sirius"     "Griffindor" empty))
  (define P3  (make-person "Regulus"    "Slytherin"  empty))
  (define P4  (make-person "Bellatrix"  "Slytherin"  empty))
  (define P5  (make-person "Andromeda"  "Slytherin"  (list P1)))
  (define P6  (make-person "Narcissa"   "Slytherin"  (list P0)))
  (define P7  (make-person "Walburga"   "Slytherin"  (list P2 P3)))
  (define P8  (make-person "Alphard"    "Slytherin"  empty))
  (define P9  (make-person "Cygnus"     "Slytherin"  (list P4 P5 P6)))
  (define P10 (make-person "Irma"       "Slytherin"  (list P7 P8 P9)))
```

original structured reference

```
   ;; Person -> Natural
   ;; Count number of people in a tree
   (check-expect (count P0) 1)
   (check-expect (count P5) 2)
   (check-expect (count P10) 11)

(define (count p)  
  (local 
    [(define (count/person p)
       (add1 (count/lop (person-kids p))))
     (define (count/lop lop)
       (cond [(empty? lop) 0]
             [else
              (+ (count/person (first lop))
                 (count/lop (rest lop)))]))]
    (count/person p)))
```

this is the solution

```
(define (count p)  
  (local 
    [(define (count/person p result todo)
       (count/lop (add1 result)
                  (append (person-kids p) todo)))
     (define (count/lop result todo)
       (cond [(empty? todo) result]
             [else
              (count/person (first todo) 
                            result
                            (rest todo))]))])
  (count/person p 0 empty))

;; Accumulator result is Natural
;; Invariant: the total computed so far
;; Accumulator todo is (listof Person)
;; Invariant: persons not yet visited by count/person
```

I have trouble understand how this comes from the initial normal mutual reference solution, could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Maybe you could post the reference solution?

Comment: What's the deal with `local`? Wouldn't `define` inside `define` be local by default?

Comment: @Sylwester In the teaching languages local defines must be inside local.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not follow the basic design recipe.
Here is an attempt to make a straight-forward solution:

```
(define-struct person (kids))

; sum : list-of-numbers -> number
(define (sum xs)
  (cond
    [(empty? xs) 0]
    [else        (+ (first xs) (sum (rest xs)))]))

; count : person -> number
(define (count p)
  (cond 
    [(empty? (person-kids p)) 1]             ; p is 1 person, 0 kids
    [else (+ 1                               ; p is 1 person and 
             (sum (map count                 ; we must sum over the
                       (person-kids p))))])) ; count of each kid
```

In chapter 30 and 31 of How to Design Programs, you can read about the conversion from this style to accumulator style (which your solution uses). Details in the conversion is in section 31.3.

[HtDP section 31.3 'Transforming Functions into Accumulator-Style'](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-39.html)